# Trying to get property of non-object?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, view, laravel-5.4

Esta é minha `View`:

```
<tbody>
    @if(isset($pessoas))
        @foreach($pessoas as $p)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$p->nome}}</td>
                <td>{{$p->idade}}</td>
                <td>{{$p->cidade->nome}}</td>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</tbody>
```

O `Controller` que passa o parâmetro **pessoas** e retorna a `View`:

```
public function verPessoas()
{      
    $pessoas = Pessoa::all();
    return view('verPessoas', compact('pessoas'));
}
```

Relação no `Model` **`Pessoa`**

```
public function cidade()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cidade');
}
```

Relação no Model **"Cidade"**

```
public function pessoa()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pessoa');
}
```

Este relacionamento é **1:N**, onde a tabela `pessoas` recebe a chave estrangeira da `cidade` (`cidade_id`), sendo uma cidade possui várias pessoas, cada pessoa pertence a uma cidade. Quando tento acessar essa `View` obtenho o ***erro***:

> `Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\PROJETO\resources\views\verPessoas.blade.php)`

Quando removo a linha

```
<td>{{$p->cidade->nome}}</td>
```

Tudo funciona normalmente, levando a crer que estou relacionando os `models` de maneira equivocada e verifiquei as tabelas do banco e seus respectivos valores, tudo esta preenchido e funcionando perfeitamente.

Gostaria de entender o que causa este ***erro*** e qual a solução apropriada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se os seus relacionamentos tiverem correto, faça assim:

***Com*** [with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
public function verPessoas()
{      
    $pessoas = Pessoa::with('cidade')->get()
    return view('verPessoas', compact('pessoas'));
}
```

***Uma razão no qual essa é a maneira recomendavel***: *nesse caso é executado duas `SQL` e a lógica do algoritmo faz a inclusão dos itens no seu destino isso tem uma grande diferencial no desempenho da aplicação, já visto que da outra forma a cada interação do `for` é feito uma nova `SQL` degradando muito a aplicação*

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)
- [Eager-loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente dessa maneira, agradeço a ajuda e também por explicar porque seria esta uma maneira recomendada.  Abraço

Answer (score 2):

Na sua relação com a outra model coloque o atributo que faz o vínculo (chave estrangeira) como segundo parâmetro, pode ser isso já que o *eloquent* precisa saber qual parametro usar na query caso o nome da sua chave estrangeira não esteja no padrão *(nome_da_tabela)*_id.

*Em Pessoa:*

```
public function cidade(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Cidade::class, 'cidade_id');
}
```

*Em Cidade:*

```
public function pessoa(){
    return $this->hasMany(Pessoa::class, 'cidade_id');
}
```

Comment: Possivelmente este é o problema, só lembrando que a definição FK só é necessária caso ela não seja `tabela_id`, o que pode ser o que está acontecendo.

Comment: @Pliavi sim, vou complementar na resposta.

Comment: a minha chave estrangeira tem o nome padrão. Testei a sugestão acima mas ainda não resolveu

Comment: @MarceloSnts pode mostrar como está seu `$fillable` ?

Comment: @Felipe Paetzold Pessoa: `protected $fillable = array('nome', 'idade');` Cidade: `protected $fillable = array('nome');`

Comment: @MarceloSnts Coloque cidade_id no fillable de pessoa

Comment: coloquei, mas ainda não está funcionando, continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: @MarceloSnts estranho, retorne dessa forma para a view entao `return view('verPessoas', ['pessoas' => $pessoas]);`, caso nao funcione você pode tentar manipular cidade como array `<td>{{$p->cidade['nome']}}</td>` mas aparentemente está tudo certo

Comment: também não deu certo, a primeira sugestão mostrou o mesmo erro e a segunda deixou um campo em branco, porém, exibiu as outras informações da mesma forma quando removo o `<td>{{$p->cidade->nome}}</td>`.

Comment: @MarceloSnts No controller faça um foreach de `$pessoas` e dentro do laço use `dd($pessoa->cidade)` e veja o que retorna

Comment: @Felipe Paetzold, desculpe, acabei não testando dessa maneira porque a solução proposta por Virgilio Novic resolveu meu problema. Agradeço a ajuda.